# Explicit form of $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ in the Dirac equation

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, conventions

I'm in an introductory particle physics class, and in performing manipulations on the Dirac equation, my instructor expands the $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ term as:

$$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu = \gamma^0 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \vec{\gamma}\cdot \vec{\nabla}$$

where $\vec{\gamma} = (\gamma^1,\gamma^2,\gamma^3)$, but to my knowledge,

$$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu = \gamma^\mu \eta_{\mu \nu} \partial^\nu = \gamma^0\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \vec{\gamma} \cdot \vec{\nabla}$$

using the convention $\eta_{\mu \nu}=\operatorname{diag}(+,-,-,-)$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: you a forgeting an extra minus sign on the $\partial^\nu = (\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, - \nabla)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You are missing the fact that he is using the convention
$$
  \nabla = (\partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3)
$$
as opposed to
$$
  \nabla = (\partial^1, \partial^2, \partial^3)
$$
The first convention is by far the most common in my experience.

Comment: I see. Now that I think about it, we didn't actually discuss the difference between $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial^\mu$. Is the only difference a minus sign in the spatial part?

Comment: Yes that's the difference in this case.  This is a special case of a more general notational phenomenon used in lots od contexts called "raising and lowering indices" with a metric.

Comment: Well, it is not only a convention. Lower indices represent covectors, and the derivative is naturally a covector.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Well, sure; it's a well-motivated convention that is consistent with other notational conventions used for vectors and covectors, but in this context the distinction is largely artificial anyway because of the tangent-cotangent isomorphism on semi-Riemannian manifolds.  Also, besides all of this highbrow talk, at some point you have to choose a definition for the symbol $\nabla$, and you might think one definition is more natural than another, but you certainly could have picked the other one if you really wanted to.

Comment: So Peter, you're saying the natural correspondence is, e.g.,$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$?

Comment: @Gino $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} = \partial_2$; one usually labels coordinate components with a superscript, and any superscript in a denominator is treated overall as a subscript.

Comment: @joshphysics, sorry I have not thought of 'the convention' as of 'the convention for $\nabla$')

Comment: @joshphysics Thanks, this is very helpful. So you're saying that $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\partial^i = g^{ii} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (not summing over $i$, and I guess the metric has to be diagonal)?

Comment: @Gino http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices That should answer most of your questions.  Also see http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry(II)/3.04/cotangent_tangent.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form (search for the phrase "raise and lower").  Also, consult any book on GR such as the first couple chapters of http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/